# change format of double like ***.***,**

Tags: android, double

I have `double amount`. Let amount to be **500000.12**. I want to set value of the amount to `TextView` like this format **500,000.12** (where 12 is cents , 500,000 is dollars).

I wrote this function and it works

```
private String getAmountAsString(double amount) {
        double integralPart = amount % 1;
        int fractionalPart = (int) (amount - integralPart);
        int integral = (int) integralPart * 100;
        String strFractional = String.format("%,d", fractionalPart);
        String strAmount = (strFractional + "." + String.valueOf(integral));

        return strAmount;
    }
```

But I think that there can be some easy and good way of doing this with java native functions. Can anybody help to find functions or some better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

various Locale can be used to format `float, double` etc. You can use:

```
String.format(Locale.<Your Locale>, "%1$,.2f", myDouble);
```

Here `.2f` represents how many digits you want after decimal. If you are not specifying any locale it will use the default locale.

In String class this method is overloaded as:

```
format(String format, Object... args)  
&
format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)
```

For more info have a look: [Link1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885254/string-format-to-format-double-in-java) and [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695230/how-to-use-java-string-format)

Comment: Thank you very much , this is what I want. One line instead of writing some function.

Comment: +1 for to the point answer. I don't know about Locale. What value I should provide for Locale ?

Answer (score 2):

Therefore `NumberFormat`s are used. They are good to handle local differents for different countries.

```
//define a local, gets automated if a point or comma is correct in this Country.
NumberFormat anotherFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormat anotherDFormat = (DecimalFormat) anotherFormat;
anotherDFormat.applyPattern("#.00");//set the number of digits afer the point
anotherDFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);// set grouping
anotherDFormat.setGroupingSize(3);//and size of grouping
double myDouble = 123456.78;
String numberWithSeparators = anotherDFormat.format(myDouble);//convert it
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to take a look at this one

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html