# how to get double value of a string with mantissa separator?

Tags: java

I have the following String:

```
String p = "33,644.234";
```

How can I convert it to double value?

Following gives  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "33,644.234"`

```
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(p));
```

kindly suggest.

Comment: Remove the comma from it?

Comment: no, i cant do it. I need the output double as 33,644.234

Comment: @AnushreeAcharjee, See the update to my answer if you want to `print` the double in that format.

Comment: thanks merlin2011. If I want the output type as double, not String, is there any way out?

Comment: The true form of a `double` in the computer is stored as a bunch of bits. Java's default way of printing doubles does not provide the `,`, which is why we need to use `String.format` to display it in a certain way.

Comment: Note also that, when you call `System.out.println`, you are implicitly converting the `double` into a `String` to display it at all. The `double` itself does not have an inherent format.

Comment: actually in my program I wont be using the output in System.out.println, rather I have to pass it to JAXRS. If I store the variable as String, in the REST response it shows as distance:"33,644.234". I was looking for an way if I can make it distance: 33,644.234

Comment: I am not familiar with `JAXRS`, but I can tell you that if you store it as a double, you will most likely not be able to force it to show the comma, unless `JAXRS` gives you a way of specifying display and parsing for `double` values.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the comma and then parse it.

```
 double d = Double.parseDouble(p.replace(",",""));
```

Based on the OP's update, he wants the double to print in the original form, with the comma. The answer to that comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885254/string-format-to-format-double-in-java).

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$,.2f", d));
```

Output:

```
33,644.23
```

Comment: Sounds good, but remember that solution won't support i18n properly

Comment: @AleZalazar, True, but I assume the OP will clarify if he needs that also.