# Round off a double while maintaining the trailing zero

Tags: java, math, double, rounding

Here is my function to roundoff a number upto two decimals but when the rounded off number is 1.50 it seems to ignore the trailing zero and just returns 1.5

```
public static double roundOff(double number) {
        double accuracy = 20;
        number = number * accuracy;
        number = Math.ceil(number);
        number = number / accuracy;
        return number;
    }
```

So if I send 1.499 it returns 1.5 where as I want 1.50

Comment: There isn't a separate `double` for 1.5 and for 1.50.  They're numerically the same, so there's only one `double` representation of them both.

Comment: Maybe your method should return `String`, rather than `double`, so that you can do whatever kind of formatting you want with it.

Comment: Are you sure about that `20`? Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do, but your method for `1.489` wouldn't return `1.49`. I would think you'd want to set accuracy to `100` for two decimal places.

Comment: @cyon, it should round it up to the next multiple of 1/20, so 1.499 will indeed become 1.5. But you're right that it doesn't gel with the "up to two decimals" comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a printing poblem:

```
double d = 1.5;
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", d)); // 1.50
```

Comment: If the result format is your local format and you want to change it, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885329/15813444

Answer (score 4):

`1.5` is, number of significant digits notwithstanding, the *same* as `1.50` (and even `1.5000000000000`).

You need to separate the *value* of the number from its *presentation.*

If you want it output with two decimal digits, just use `String.format`, such as with:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 1.50000;
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", d));
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1.5
1.50
```

If you still want a function that does all that for you *and* gives you a specific format, you'll need to return the string with something like:

```
public static String roundOff(double num, double acc, String fmt) {
    num *= acc;
    num = Math.ceil(num);
    num /= acc;
    return String.format(fmt, num);
}
```

and call it with:

```
resultString = roundOff(value, 20, "%.2f"); // or 100, see below.
```

This will allow you to tailor the accuracy and output format in any way you desire, although you can still hard-code the values if you want simplicity:

```
public static String roundOff(double num) {
    double acc = 20;
    String fmt = "%.2f";
    num *= acc;
    num = Math.ceil(num);
    num /= acc;
    return String.format(fmt, num);
}
```

---

One final note: your question states that you want to round to "two decimals" but that doesn't quite gel with your use of `20` as the accuracy, since that will round it up to the next multiple of `1/20`. If you *really* want it rounded up to two decimals, the value you should be using for `accuracy` is `100`.

Comment: In your last little snippet, you have two different variables called `acc` (one parameter, one local) and two different variables called `fmt`.  Then you use a variable called `accuracy` which appears not to exist.  You might want to fix this.

Comment: @David, _damn_ those cut'n'paste errors :-) Thanks for that, fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I really should have just edited it myself.  It was clear from the words that you meant those two variables to be locals, not parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to format it as a `String` in order to do that. Java, like most languages, will drop the trailing zero.

```
String.format("%.2f", number);
```

So you can either return a `String` (change your return type from double) or just format it when you need to display it using the code above. You can [read the JavaDoc for Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) in order to understand all of the possibilities with number of decimal places, comma placement, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Jean's solution which is the same as your's worked smoothly.

Comment: Just one note, though it doesn't affect the output: the `1` in your format string has little effect here since it sets the minimum field width for the whole thing. Since you're also specifying it be of the form `.99`, it already has to be more than that.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo. I had it as something different (formatted with comma separator which I use personally) and then changed it to be simpler and in my haste left the "1." in. Corrected now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want is a String output

```
double number = roundOff(1.499);//1.5

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String fromattedDouble = decimalFormat.format(number);//1.50
```

The function roundOff is the same as you mentioned in your question.