# Read Decimal value from JSON response in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

We have an API which returns response below:

```
{
"Amount": 10.2300,
"name": "Test"
}
```

`Amount` will have 4 places after decimal. We need to validate that decimal places should be 4 places,
below is the code:

```
String strres = response.asString();
System.out.println("strres" + strres);

JSONObject data = new JSONObject(strres);
float myFloatValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(data.getDouble("Amount")).floatValue();
System.out.println("The Amount " + myFloatValue);
```

After execution we get : `myFloatValue = 10.23` only, and not `10.2300` hence decimal places is less than 4.
Please suggest how can we read without loss of decimal places.

```
sAmount = response.jsonPath().get("Amount").toString()

String[] splitter = sAmount.toString().split("\\.");
splitter[0].length(); 
splitter[1].length();
```

When storing to `String` variable, also getting same value: `10.23`

Comment: Hi & Welcome! :) they are not "lost" ...u just have to "print em"! ;)

Comment: You are not loosing precision as ending zeros are not significant. If you want to keep them use String instead.

Comment: @GweltazNiquel in string , getting same result.

Comment: might be dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832131/round-off-a-double-while-maintaining-the-trailing-zero

Comment: it is because, when you are converting to string, you are not formatting properly. if you directly convert double to string, you will lose trailing zeros

Comment: Why not fix your API instead of jumping through irrelevant hoops?

Answer (score 2):

You can do so:

```
//...
  float myFloatValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(23.0).floatValue();
  String formatted = String.format("%.4f", myFloatValue);
  System.out.println(formatted);
//...
```

Comment: After formating need to save in String then assert that value after decimal is 4 places, can u help how to proceed