# How can you suppress the automatic suffixing of ".0" for integral cases when stringifying a Double?

Tags: java

Consider

```
Double f = 2.0;
String s = f.toString();
```

The resulting string `s` is "2.0". How can I format `f` so the answer for the case where `f` doesn't have a decimal part doesn't have the `.0` appended? (For cases where `f` has a decimal part, I need that to be included.). Yes, for some reason, the `toString()` method on a `Double` appends `.0` for the case where the `Double` is an integer.

A nasty hack would be

```
f % 1.0 == 0.0 ? new Integer(f.intValue()).toString() : f.toString();
```

but to me that looks terrible.

Comment: Use a `DecimalFormat` to get any formatting you like.

Comment: Btw,  `new Integer(f.intValue()).toString()` -> `String.valueOf( f.intValue() )` or `"" + f.intValue()`.

Comment: @Thomas: The ternary doesn't look so bad if you write it like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.format() to format double in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885254/string-format-to-format-double-in-java)

Comment: Not really. That dupe is about inserting decimal and thousands separator. Mine is about suppressing an unnecessary .0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question properly, you may try this:

```
    double f = 2.0;
    int i = (int)f;
    if (i==f){
        String s = String.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#").format(f));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    else{
        String s = String.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(f)); // for example
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

//now if the number after the point is fully zero, it will not take it
```

results

```
f=2.0 -> s=2
f=2.005 -> s=2.005
```

EDIT: in a few lines if there is no specific "number of digits" after decimal -> you can use the ternary operator like this

```
double f = 2.000;
int i = (int)f;
String s = (f==i)? String.valueOf(i): String.valueOf(f);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Yes dealing with the integer case separately does seem to be the only way.

Comment: Now this is wonderful. I much prefer the symmetry in the ternary to the way I have it. I don't really like using `toString()`. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a several help methods of several classes to achieve the same result:

```
    Double f = 2.0;
    String s = null;
    // option1: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-
    s = String.valueOf(f.intValue());
    System.out.println(s);
    // option2: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-
    s = Integer.toString(f.intValue());
    System.out.println(s);
    // option3: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-
    s = String.format("%.0f", f);
    System.out.println(s);
    // option4: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat-java.lang.String-
    s = new DecimalFormat("#").format(f);
    System.out.println(s);
```

for an input like:

```
Double f = 21231.232222323;
```

the output will be: **21231**

Comment: But these seem to truncate a decimal like 2.1 or 123.456

Comment: which option do you mean?

Comment: Well `f.intVal` is certainly going to remove the decimal component. My understanding is that "%.0f" will do the same, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using the number format (for more advanced formatting)

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(nf.format(f));
```

Comment: Will this preserve the decimal parts of things like 2.1 and 666.6?

Comment: you are right, I fixed the answer. The NumberFormat should not print unnecessary decimals when not needed

Comment: Won't this truncate 123.456 to 123.45?

Comment: it will, you may skip setting the maximum fraction digits. It is there to demonstrate the options for formatting

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no trivial formatter that does this. Using (thanks to @Thomas for the simplification of the integer case)

```
f % 1.0 == 0.0 ? String.valueOf(f.intValue()) : f.toString();
```

seems to be the best way.

`f % 1.0` is a good way to test for integral `f` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, try `DecimalFormat`.

```
static void show(double v){
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##########.##");
    System.out.println(format.format(v));
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    show(1.1);
    show(1.0);
    show(1.15);
    show(1.116);
}
```

The out put will be:

1.1

1

1.15

1.12

Which seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: No. 1.116 needs to be 1.116.

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of places? Just add more `#`s.