# How to compulsorily add two decimals in result of type decimal?

Tags: java, number-formatting

- Result have two decimal points compulsorily(ex: 10.**56**, 34.**56**).
- In my case: 10.0 should be **10.00** and 10.5 should be **10.50** and 10.3494 should be **10.35**.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your version with `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: So what you have done from your side . can you share that ?

Comment: @soorapadman I have shared solution below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195260/6508381).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This code worked for me!

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String Input="75.74306816000052";
  String Input2 = "26.9";
  BigDecimal Output= new BigDecimal(Input).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
  System.out.println(Output.setScale(2)); 
  BigDecimal Output2= new BigDecimal(Input2).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
  System.out.println(Output2.setScale(2)); }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

A `decimal` number in Java (and most languages) will always have full prescision. Java doesn't have a concept of `10.0` and `10.00` being different things. So if I write:

```
double x = 10.0;
```

Then `x` is actually `10.0000000000000....`

(The details of the *exact* prescision are [surprisingly complicated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) and largely irrelevant so I won't go into it here, but it's more than enough for every day use.)

What you can do is *display* a double as a string, rounded to 2 decimal places, like so:

```
String str = String.format(".2f", x);
```

In this case `str` will be `"10.00"`. There are a lots of other options for `String.format()`, I suggest you [search for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885254/string-format-to-format-double-in-java)! Note that the result is a string, not a number, so you cannot now do `str+2.0` or any mathematical operations like that. This means that formatting has to be done when you want to output / display your result.

The other thing you can do is *round* the double to 2 decimal places:

```
double y = Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

The result will still have full prescision, but the `Math.round()` function will have rounded the number to the nearest integer. So if I had started with `x=10.3494;` (it's always full prescision, actually `x` is `10.34940000...`), then `y` would now be `10.3500000...`.

Comment: According to `BigDecimal.equals`, 10.0 and 10.00 are _not_ equal.

Comment: Saying "it is complicated" without giving any further hint or at least a link is discouraging.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is a different kettle of fish - and beyond the scope of my reply! Have taken on board the other feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If a fixed precision in string format is enough for you just use `num.toFixed(2)` which in your case 10.3494 turns to "10.35".